# Mathematican proof or physicist proof of a theorem?

Tags: proof-writing, mathematical-physics

I am writing a document, where I have proved a so-called theorem coming from a physicist paper. It is not a mathematical theorem in the sense that have only done  the computations and did not check some necessary hypothesis (differentiability issues).

Is it fair if I say that I give a rigorous proof of the result obtain in the paper [paper name] ?

Comment: If you write down a link to that proof perhaps some of us can take a peek at it and decide...

Comment: It might be simple prejudice, but I'm instantly suspicious of any paper at least remotely related to mathematics which is not typeset in LaTeX. The justification is atrocious. And I can't even find the theorem, much less the proof without reading through the entire thing. In any event (I haven't read the entire thing), if it is as you say, I would say that the proof is valid only under additional assumption of as much smoothness as is used.

Comment: Otherwise, I could politely mention that this proof is correct, if we admit that the Brownian motion is differentiable. (They use Taylor together with the Brownian motion...)

Comment: So do you really mean that the proof in section 2 is by someone in the medical profession, or are you just forgetting that we call people who do physics *physicists*
?

Comment: I am totally aware that the aim of physicists is different to the aim of mathematicians. That is why I didn't want to criticize this article. My major problem was to find a formulation which isn't haughty.

Comment: I was really thinking more along the lines of correcting the three occurrences of "physician" to "physicist." That is a rather more egregious error than being haughty.

Answer (score 1):

In this paper I can not find the term "theorem", where do you refer to. I know this theory quite well as it is a foundation of synergetics in physics. In physics unlike math often one presents theories with proof that does not repeat common known contexts/consensus of physicists. In this article I find only one time the word "proof" and that refers to another reference.

The answer to your question is diligently said: yes if you are writing a math paper you can say that and do so.